# implement negation (\+ or not/1) in WAM Prolog

Tags: prolog, negation

How would you implement negation-by-failure (`\+`) in WAM? Or (->;)soft-cut. We assume cut is implemented.

For example, once is described by swi-pl as,

```
once(Goal) :-
    Goal,
    !.
```

To add another source,  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warren_Abstract_Machine) itself simply has a vague "execute \+".

Negation implies taking the value of a predicate, i.e. if it's true it's false and vice-versa.
Rather than returning a value, though, WAM describes 'failure' as an operation. I'd implement it as `goto fail` etc.

I'm having trouble understanding where exactly the value is (in the high-level description, Goal has a truth value, but in a low-level basis it is an operation) or if you'd extend the wam and how.

Comment: that would just be (goal,!, false;true)...nvm

Comment: `\+(Goal_0) :- call(Goal_0), !, fail ; true.` - there is nothing WAM specific here. It says `execute((\+)/1)])` as it just executes that definition.